# Decorate the generator with parameters

Tags: python, decorator

Here is my generator that takes an array input and iterates over it in a specific way:

```
def array_gen(answer):
    n = len(answer)
    m = len(answer[0])
    elem=0
    i = n
    j = 0
    curr = 0
    steps = [(-1,0), (0,1), (1,0), (0,1)]
    while not (elem == n*m):
        if (((i == n - 1) and (j != 0)) or i == 0):
            curr += 1
        i += steps[curr % 4][0]
        j += steps[curr % 4][1]
        elem+=1
        yield answer[i][j]
```

Now, I want to write a decorator that returns pairs(current and the next one) of elements of the array, while I am iterating through the array. Can someone give me some idea for achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pairwise` recipe from the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and make it a decorator:

> ```
> from itertools import tee
>
> def pairwise(iterable):
>     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
>     a, b = tee(iterable)
>     next(b, None)
>     return zip(a, b)
> ```

```
from functools import wraps

def pairwise_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return pairwise(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

This happily works with generators (as do all functions in the `itertools` module) and returns a `zip` object (a special kind of generator) in Python 3.

Example usage:

```
@pairwise_decorator
def f(n):
    return range(n)

list(f(5))
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

To make this more general (call any function on the output of the decorated function), make this a decorator accepting an argument:

```
def call_after(outer_func):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return outer_func(func(*args, **kwargs))
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@call_after(pairwise)
def f(n):
    return range(n)

@call_after(lambda x: grouper(x, 3))
def g(n):
    return range(n)

list(f(5))
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
list(g(5))
# [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, None)]
```